# How Can i tell Python Curl to use my method of Transport?

Tags: python, sockets, curl

I have code in Python:

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://server-A.com/form.php'
res = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print res.read()
```

And i want to tell it to use my TCP method to send it in Transport Layer, is it possible ?
My real question is : How can we program our code in two network layer ?

My transport is some thing like [this](http://www.binarytides.com/raw-socket-programming-in-python-linux/) link.

Comment: does your TCP implementation provide file objects with the same interface as the normal ones?

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, No i change some flag in tcp but the rest is same as normal one.

Comment: The link you provided is to use raw sockets. Did you implement your own version of TCP on top of them?

Comment: No i don't implement anything more , i just want to send the http request with raw socket to a website.

Comment: websites use TCP, you can't send them data that is not in a TCP stream!

Answer (score 0):

.HTTP always uses TCP.

HTTPU uses UDP but I've seen it used just for SSTP, I don't know if other applications use it.

urllib2 uses the httplib open internally and I couldn't find any function that accepts an open socket with the server, so I guess the answer is: **no, you can't**

Comment: there must be a way, what if i do not use Curl, is there another library.

Comment: send the HTTP request yourself instead.